# SSRS - cannot export large files to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, export

I need to give users the option to download a report into Excel.
The report includes about 70,000 records (and about 50 fields).

The report generates within about 1.5 minutes, but when the user tries to download, nothing happens.
(In Explorer, a second tab opens and the progress wheel keeps turning...)

I have tried on a filtered list of about 10,000 and it downloads quickly without issue.
However, at 30,000 it already has issues.
I tried from this from the server itself, so network issues were ruled out.)

I also tried sending out the report by email subscription, but this also failed.

Is there a way to go around this size limitation?
Or to give the user similar flexibility on the reports server itself, as he would have in Excel, without building in every possible filter into the report itself. (Probably too big a question here.)

Comment: Are you running into any Excel limitations?  Max # rows or columns?

Can you access the report via ReportServer and a render command instead of through Report Manager?  For example, http://<yourserver>/ReportServerPages/ReportViewer.aspx?<reportpath>&Param1=X&Param2=Y&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=EXCEL

Comment: According to our IT team, there is a shortage of disk space on the server.They are trying to resolve that, and I'll try again then.